# How do I change my sFTP account

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sftp

My developer set up an Instance in Amazon EC2. It gave me access to the server that I can use PuTTY to connect to it, It's also the same details that i provide in my sFTP.

How do I change these login details? I need to change the login details for my server and the one I use for sFTP.

I'm running on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: I think a google search with the terms `change user password ubuntu` would have given you an answer a lot fasted than having to type/submit a question here.

Comment: I did few google search but i'm confuse on how it works. Because I might just change my password for ubuntu and it will not affect my sftp. But Thanks.

Comment: SFTP uses your regular login.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log into the server via SSH (ie with Putty) and run `passwd`. It will prompt you to enter your current password and then a new password two times. Done.

(once you change it via SSH, it also applies to sFTP. It's the same thing)

Comment: oh ok that's great! thanks for the help man. I really appreciate it.